# How to avoid memory leaks in program with dynamical array containing pointers to objects?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm having trouble with memory usage in my homework program, which is used to store information about companies and its' owners. Class СompanyTemplate represents this info.

```
public:
CompanyTemplate (const string & oName,
                 const string & oAddr,
                 const string & cName,
                 const string & cAddr);
```

Another Class CCompanyIndex is used to store multiple records using a dynamical array of pointers (I'm not allowed to use vectors). Here's CCompanyIndex constructor:

```
CCompanyIndex :: CCompanyIndex (void)
{
allocated = 1000;
current_size = 0;
pole = new CompanyTemplate* [allocated];
for (int i=0; i<allocated; i++)
{
    pole[i] = NULL;
}
}
```

CCompanyIndex also provides methods Add (add record), Del (delete record), Search(search an information about owner's company. 
I'm having trouble with the Add method, although all basic tests are good, I have memory leaks, as valgrind says, in Add method.

```
bool CCompanyIndex :: Add( const string & oName,
                       const string & oAddr,
                       const string & cName,
                       const string & cAddr )
{

int pos = findPos(oName, oAddr);
        if(pos != -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
if ((current_size)>=allocated)
{
    CompanyTemplate ** temp;
    allocated = allocated*2+1;
    temp = new CompanyTemplate* [allocated];
    for (int i=0; i<current_size; i++)
    {
        temp[i]=pole[i];
    }
pole = temp;

for (int i=0; i<current_size; i++ )
{
    if ((pole[i])->Compare(oName,oAddr)<0)
    {
        current_size++;
        for (int k=current_size-1; k>=i; k--)
        {

        pole[i] = new Comp   pole[k+1]=pole[k];
        }anyTemplate(oName, oAddr, cName,cAddr);
        return true;
    }
}

pole[current_size] = new CompanyTemplate(oName, oAddr, cName,cAddr);
current_size++;
return true;
}
```

Array elements reallocating works as expected, more likely I have an error in destructor, but still can't find.
Here it is:

```
CCompanyIndex :: ~CCompanyIndex (void)
{
for (int i=0; i<allocated; i++)
{
    delete pole[i];
}
delete [] pole;
pole = NULL;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Avoiding raw pointers wherever you can should be a good start...

Comment: To elaborate on @PlasmaHH, using std::shared_ptr and std::unique_ptr (and std::vector, alas) to manage your resources will virtually eliminate memory leaks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if ownership is unclear, just use `std::shared_ptr`.

of course in a professional setting a better answer might be to analyze better and get a better idea of ownership, like, is it really shared?

but absent that, use a `std::shared_ptr`.

---

by the way, it looks like your class fails to handle *copying* properly. this is called the "rule of three" (or for c++11, the "rule of five"). essentially, if you define either of destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment operator, then you most likely need *all three* in order to deal properly with copying.

but the simplest is to not define such operations but instead use standard library containers, like `std::vector`, and standard library smart pointers, like `std::shared_ptr`.

e.g. instead of defining `pole` as a raw pointer (to array), define it as a `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

With such a general title, the general answer will: use a `vector` of `shared_ptr`.

But I assumed that your homework is to implement a kind of `std::vector<CompanyTemplate>` using "low" level C++, witout STL and smart pointers (with otherwise is the best way of using c++). So:

Maybe you have other error, but here are two:

```
CompanyTemplate ** temp;
allocated = allocated*2+1;
temp = new CompanyTemplate* [allocated];
int i=0
for (; i<current_size; i++)
{
    temp[i]=pole[i];
}
for (; i<allocated ; i++)  // you want to make NULL the new pointers
{
    temp[i]=NULL
}
delete [] pole;    // delete old array.
pole=temp;
```